# Does notify/notifyall release the lock being held

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I am confused a bit about wait and notify/notifyAll.

I know there is a lock for every java object. I know wait will release the lock for other thread. How about notify/notifyall? Does notify/notifyAll release the lock it is holding for other thread?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No -- `notify`/`notifyAll` don't release locks like `wait` does. The awakened thread can't run until the code which called `notify` releases its lock.

This is what the Javadoc says:

> The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.

Comment: thanks , but according to my reading, notify/notifyall will wake up the threads that are waiting, if notigy/notifyall is not releasing the lock, how the waiting threads can pick up to test somehting already changed?

Comment: My understanding is that they must wait for the lock to be released normally. So if we did `synchronized (x) { x.notifyAll(); foo(); }`, waiting threads could not run until `foo()` finished.

Comment: @icn when the thread executing the notify exits, the lock is released so one of the threads it awoke can now acquire the lock. The others (if any) will block until the lock is available.

Comment: @Daniel Effectively yes, but to be precise, an awaiting thread could not run until the currently executing thread leaves the synchronized block (i.e. the last `}`) - which of course is after `foo()` finished (or anything else in that block).

Answer (score 16):

- **wait( )** tells the calling thread to give up the monitor and go to sleep until some other
  thread enters the same monitor and calls notify( ).
- **notify( )** wakes up a thread that called wait( ) on the same object.
- **notifyAll( )** wakes up all the threads that called wait( ) on the same object. The
  highest priority thread will run first.

Comment: Yes sir, notifyAll() wakes up all waiting threads that are waiting on this object that they can run.

Comment: `notify()` will wake **a** thread that is waiting on the object, **not necessarily** the first thread.

Comment: still want to clarify a bit, the thread including notifyall will realse the lock right away after calling notifyall  or the lock will be realsed after completing the method  that contains notifyall

Comment: The lock will be released just after calling notifyAll().

Comment: @dotNET are you saying that notifyAll itself releases the lock? I don't think this is the case. Can you point to documentation?

Comment: @Daniel if the method is synchronised the lock will be released after completing the method otherwise the waiting thread will get the source just after the notify() is been called.

Comment: Well-written code should release the lock quickly after a notify, but there's no requirement... any code could be placed between the notify and the end of the synchronized block (or the end of the method, if it's a synchronized method).

Answer (score 15):

I have to **disagree** with people who say **`notifyAll()` releases the lock** on the object over which waiting and notifying threads are being synchronized.

An example:

`Consumer` class contains a block:

```
synchronized(sharedObject){
if(sharedObject.isReadyToConsume() == false){
     sharedObject.wait();
}else {
    sharedObject.doTheThing();
    System.out.println("consumer consuming...");
 }
```

}

Scenario: **Consumer class** gets the lock on the **sharedObject** object, enters exclusively (it's inside the sync block) and sees that **sharedObject** has nothing ready yet (nothing to consume :) ) and it calls `wait()` method on the **sharedObject**. That way it releases the lock (stops the execution there!) and waits to be notified to continue when another Thread (Producer maybe) calls `sharedObject.notify();` or `sharedObject.notifyAll();`. When it gets notified it continues from the **wait()** line

It's the **sharedObject** that keeps track of threads that asked it to be notified. When some Thread calls **sharedObject.notifyAll()** method the **sharedObject** will notify the waiting threads to wake up...
Now, the tricky part is that a thread naturally **releases the lock of the object when it reaches the end of its synchronized(sharedObject){} block**. THe question is **what happens if I call notifyAll() in that block**??? **notifyAll()** wakes up the waiting threads, but the lock is still owned by the Thread that  has just call **notifyAll()**

Look at the Producer snippet:

```
synchronized(sharedObject){
//We are exlusively working with sharedObject and noone can enter it
[... changing the object ...]
sharedObject.notifyAll();     //notifying the waiting threads to wake up

Thread.sleep(1000);           //Telling the current thread to go to sleep. It's holding the LOCK
System.out.println("awake...");
```

}

If **notifyAll()** would release the lock then the "awake..." would get printed out after the Consumer classes already start working with the **sharedObject**. This is not the case... The output shows that the Consumer is consuming the sharedObject after the Producer exits its sync block...

- *wait()* - releases the lock and continues on the next line when it gets notified
- *notify(), notifyAll()* - don't release the lock. They simply make waiting threads runnable again (not idle). They will have the right to enter when the
  current thread reaches the end of its sync block and the Thread
  scheduleder tells them that the lock has been released. The fight for
  the lock begins again

Answer (score 6):

Lets say bunch of Readers wants to read updated Value of certain Resource, which is going to be updated by Writer. Then how Reader knows that Resource Fields have been updated by Writer.

Therefore to Synchronize such cases between Readers and Writers on common resource, three final methods of Object class have been used.

- wait()
- notify()
- notifyAll()

**Wait** : Readers wants to read updated value of resource, they register with resource object i.e when update happens on same object and when Writer notify it, readers will try to acquire lock on resource and read the updated resource.
 - Wait only being invoked when Reader have Lock Object, here in our case it is resource.
 - Once wait method is called, Reader releases the Lock Object.
 -  Now Only for the same registered Object(resource) Reader will get notification signals.
 - If Reader invokes wait on Object, which is different from Object Writer used for sending notification, Reader will never gets the notification signal.
 - Once Reader(s) are notified, now Reader(s) will try to content for the Lock(one of them gets the lock) read the updated value of resource. Similarly other Readers also gets turn to acquire lock and read the updated value.
 - Once Reader read the updated value, perform there Business Logic and come out from Synchronized Block, Reader will release the lock so that other Readers can acquire it.

**Notify**: Writer enters the Synchronized Block, after acquiring lock performs his Business Logic, update the resource Object, once resource Object is updated it will notify the waiting threads(Readers) whom are waiting on same Lock.
 - Notify signal to only one waiting Thread, which is decided by underlying Java Thread Manager
 - Once Writer signals notify(), then it doesn't means Reader rushed immediately to read the updates values. Firstly writer must release the Lock, which it will do once it comes out of Synchronized block.Once Lock is being released and waiting threads are notified, then [In case of notify()] notified Thread will acquire the Lock[Released by Writer] and then enter the Synchronized Block and completes from where he left[i.e statements after wait()].

**Notify-All**: In notifyAll, all threads who are registered with resource lock, will get the notifications.
 - Once notifyAll() is triggered, all threads waiting on same lock will get the signal and are ready in contention to acquire the lock.
 - Once Writer finishes its Job and release the Lock, Any one Reader will acquire the lock[which Thread, again decided by underlying Java Thread Manager Implementation].
 - Once the Reader gets the Lock, it will enter in Synchronized Block, where he left[i.e after wait() method] performs it tasks and on completing the Synchronized Block releases the Lock. 
 - Now Other remaining Threads will try to acquire the Lock, anyone of them will get it, enters synchronized block, completes its task and then release the Lock.
 - This process will keep on till all Registered Readers complete there Job.

---

Now we will see the Code for it. Also we will discuss the Code also. :

Basic Overview Of code : It consists of Three classes

- Resource Class : On which Lock will be acquired and wait() and notify(), notifyAll() will be invoked.
- ReaderTask : Implements Runnable interface, implies readers jobs, wants to read updated Value of resource object.
- WriterTask : Implements Runnable interface, implies writer jobs, will update the resource object and notify registered waiting threads.
- Demo Class: which will create Let say 3 Readers and 1 Writer Thread, Bind Respective Tasks to them and start the threads.

---

Resource.java

```
   public class Resource {
      private String mesg;

          public void setMesg(String mesg){
         this.mesg =mesg;
      }
      public String getMesg(){
         return this.mesg;
      }
    }
```

---

WaitThreadTask.java

```
public class WaitThreadTask implements Runnable {

    private Resource resource;

    public WaitThreadTask(Resource resource){
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        synchronized(resource){
            System.out.println("Before Reading Updated Value By : " +Thread.currentThread().getName() );
            //We need to Take care to get the updated value, so waiting for writer thread to update value.
            try {
                //Release resource Lock & wait till any notification from Writer.
                resource.wait();
                System.out.println("Waiting is Over For : "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Read Updated Value
            System.out.println("Updated Value of Resource Mesg :" + resource.getMesg() + " Read By :" +Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

---

WriterThreadTask.java

```
public class WriterThreadTask implements Runnable{

    private Resource resource;

    public WriterThreadTask(Resource resource){
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        synchronized(resource){
            System.out.println("Before Updating Resource By : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            //Updating resource Object Message
            resource.setMesg("Hi How are You !!!");
            resource.notify();
            //resource.notifyAll();
            //Once Writer Comes Out from Synch Block, Readers will Content to read the values.
            System.out.println("Task Done By Writer Thread.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

ThreadDemo.java

```
public class ThreadDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        //Create Single Resource Object, which can act as Lock on Writer and Readers.

        Resource lock = new Resource();

        //Three Readers and One Writer runnable Tasks.
        Runnable taskR1 = new WaitThreadTask(lock);
        Runnable taskR2 = new WaitThreadTask(lock);
        Runnable taskR3 = new WaitThreadTask(lock);
        Runnable taskW1 = new WriterThreadTask(lock);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(taskR1, "Reader1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(taskR2, "Reader2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(taskR3, "Reader3");
        Thread t4 = new Thread(taskW1, "Writer1");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        /*try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        t4.start();
    }

}
```

---

*Code Observations* :

- Both notify()/notifyAll() and wait() : works only on the Lock Objects they already acquire. For example : Synchornized(ObjectA) {......// ... // ObjectB.wait() or ObjectB.notify() or ObjectB.notifyAll() ...} then It will throw IllegalMonitorStateException. Therefore care must be taken that lock must be acquired before calling any of above three methods with same lock.Even If you simply write notify() or wait() or notifyAll(), then still it will throw IllegalMonitorStateException because [It suggest lock must be acquired on this Object, again which is not the case].
- Reader will only able to receive signals on which same notification is send. If wait is happening on Object which is different from Object on which notification is being send, then Readers will never get the notification and hence they will wait forever.
- Readers which are registered before Writer able to send the notification, Only those readers will get it. Because if Writer sends notification first, before reader registered to Object, they will not receive the signals as Signals are already being missed : **Missed Signals**
- **Reader and Writer should acquire Lock on same Object and should invoke wait/notification signals on same Object**. If the above code is modified as, instead of using resource for locks and wait and notify, If we use this. What will happen ? Well .. All readers will wait forever, Because readers registered with different Objects of WaitThreadTask and writer notify on WriterThreadTask. Therefore none of the Reader will receive notification signals, as they registered to receive signals on respective WaitThreadTask Object and not on WriterThreadTask Object.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ProducerConsumerInJava {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println("How to use wait and notify method in Java"); 
      System.out.println("Solving Producer Consumper Problem"); 
      Queue<Integer> buffer = new LinkedList<>(); 
      int maxSize = 10; 
      Thread producer = new Producer(buffer, maxSize, "PRODUCER"); 
      Thread consumer = new Consumer(buffer, maxSize, "CONSUMER"); 
      producer.start(); 
      consumer.start(); 
    }
}

class Producer extends Thread {
   private Queue<Integer> queue; 
   private int maxSize; 
   public Producer(Queue<Integer> queue, int maxSize, String name){ 
            super(name); this.queue = queue; this.maxSize = maxSize; 
   }

   public void run() { 
     while (true) { 
              synchronized (queue) { 
                    while (queue.size() == maxSize) { 
                          try { 
                                System.out .println("Queue is full, " +                         
                         "Producer thread waiting for " + "consumer to take 
                          something from queue"); 
                          queue.wait(); 
                    } catch (Exception ex) { 
                        ex.printStackTrace(); 
                        } 
                }
      Random random = new Random(); 
      int i = random.nextInt(); 
      System.out.println("Producing value : " + i); 
      queue.add(i); 
      queue.notifyAll(); 
     } 
    } 
  } 
  }

 class Consumer extends Thread {
   private Queue<Integer> queue; 
   private int maxSize; 
   public Consumer(Queue<Integer> queue, int maxSize, String name){ 
            super(name); this.queue = queue; this.maxSize = maxSize; 
   }

   public void run() { 
     while (true) { 
              synchronized (queue) { 
                    while (queue.isEmpty()) { 
                          try { 
                                System.out .println("Queue is empty," +                         
                         "Consumer thread is waiting" +
                          " for producer thread to put something in queue");
                          queue.wait(); 
                    } catch (Exception ex) { 
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  } 
       System.out.println("Consuming value : " + queue.remove()); 
       queue.notifyAll(); 
      } 
    } 
  } 
  }
```

This is an example of Consumer and Producer program.

Output of the above program after execution is written below:

```
How to use wait and notify 
method in Java Solving Producer Consumper Problem 
Queue is empty,Consumer thread is waiting for producer thread to put 
something in queue 

Producing value : -1692411980 
Producing value : 285310787 
Producing value : -1045894970 
Producing value : 2140997307 
Producing value : 1379699468 
Producing value : 912077154 
Producing value : -1635438928 
Producing value : -500696499 
Producing value : -1985700664 
Producing value : 961945684 
Queue is full, Producer thread waiting for consumer to take something from 
queue Consuming value : -1692411980 
Consuming value : 285310787 
Consuming value : -1045894970 
 Consuming value : 2140997307 
Consuming value : 1379699468 
Consuming value : 912077154 
Consuming value : -1635438928 
Consuming value : -500696499 
Consuming value : -1985700664 
Consuming value : 961945684 
Queue is empty,Consumer thread is waiting for producer thread to put 
something  in queue 

Producing value : 118213849
```

So, what we can conclude is, notifyAll() or notify() will not release the lock. have a look at the output, Producing value and Consuming value are not printed alternatively i.e there are printed separately.

Hence, **notify/ notifyAll will not release lock**

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-use-wait-notify-and-notifyall-in.html#ixzz57kdToLX6

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my understanding and to provide an example for all to show when the lock is released, I have added print statements to the following code after the call to notify()/NotifyAll():

```
class ThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shared s = new Shared();
        new Producer(s).start();
        new Consumer(s).start();
    }
}

class Shared {
    private char c = '\u0000';
    private boolean writeable = true;

    synchronized void setSharedChar(char c) {
        while (!writeable)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

        this.c = c;
        writeable = false;
        notifyAll();
        System.out.println("setSharedChar notify() called - still in synchronized block.");
    }

    synchronized char getSharedChar() {
        while (writeable)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

        writeable = true;
        notifyAll();
        System.out.println("getSharedChar notify() called - still in synchronized block.");

        return c;
    }
}

class Producer extends Thread {
    private Shared s;

    Producer(Shared s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Starting producer thread.");
        for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++) {
            System.out.println("Producer thread getting ready to create a char.");
            try {
                Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            s.setSharedChar(ch);
            System.out.println(ch + " produced by producer.");
        }
    }
}

class Consumer extends Thread {
    private Shared s;

    Consumer(Shared s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Starting consumer thread.");
        char ch;

        do {
            System.out.println("Consumer thread getting ready to read a char.");
            try {
                Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            ch = s.getSharedChar();
            System.out.println(ch + " consumed by consumer.");
        } while (ch != 'Z');
    }
}
```

When I ran this example enough times, there was a point where I did eventually see the output of the program show:

```
...
F produced by producer.
Producer thread getting ready to create a char.
getSharedChar notify() called - still in synchronized block.
F consumed by consumer.
Consumer thread getting ready to read a char.
setSharedChar notify() called - still in synchronized block.
G produced by producer.
Producer thread getting ready to create a char.
getSharedChar notify() called - still in synchronized block.
setSharedChar notify() called - still in synchronized block.
G consumed by consumer.
```

Since the output getSharedChar is able to appear **before** setSharedChar, it appears that the lock is being released immediately or not required to reenter the synchronized getSharedChar() function by the call to notifyAll().  The lock may still be in place, but if you can reenter the function without it, what is the difference?
I was able to see similar output substituting notify() for notifyAll().  This was done on Java 1.7.0_15 on a 64 bit Windows 7 system.

Answer (score 0):

**wait():** Virtually every object in Java posses a monitor, to enter inside any synchronized block a thread has to first acquire this monitor and then only he can enter this synchronized block. As critical section of the code is executed by a single thread at a time so it has a great impact on overall performance of the application. So in place of holding the resource(monitor) threads can be asked to leave the critical section and wait for some time. To achieve this behaviour Java has provided a wait() api directly in Object class.

So any time a thread encounter a wait() API, it drops the current monitor plus all other monitors it holds and go to waiting state linked the current object. Its important to understand that that went to the waiting state in the context of object for which thread acquired the monitor first.. In a conceptual way i explain, every object holds a container house where all waiting threads are held.
There are multiple ways a Thread can come out of this container house of Object. Lets see..

- When another thread comes and rings the bell once, In Java by calling
  notify() method on the same object.
- When another thread comes and rings multiple time, one of the Thread
  gets a chance to come out of Object’s container house. In Java we can
  do this by calling notifyAll() on the same object.
- If we have the reference of the Thread waiting in container house.
  Calling interrupt() on the Thread object pops it out of waiting state
  and brings it the exception block of the Object.
- There are overloaded wait(long milliseconds) and wait(long millSec,
  int nanos) methods. As the time over the Thread is eligible to come
  out of waiting state and contest for Object monitor again. In case
  Thread fails to acquire the monitor after timeout also then it has to
  wait for notify() calls only.

**notify():** If the objects container house has multiple threads in waiting state then calling notify() on the this object given chance to one the thread to proceed. But after coming out of the waiting state the thread still has to contest for the object monitor and if it succeeds in getting the monitor it continue its execution otherwise thread will come back to waiting state. So notify() also has to be called from the synchronized block. If the notify() is not called from synchronized context then it thorws IllegalMonitorStateException.

**notifyAll():** Calling notifyAll() on the Object makes sure all the threads in Object container house are awakened but once awakened they have to compete with each other or any other thread wants to acquire the object monitor. Which ever thread succeeds continue its executions others have to go back to waiting state and settle in object container house. As notify(), notifyAll() should also be called in synchronized context.

Explanation Taken from http://coder2design.com/thread-communication/

Answer (score -2):

Calling `notify()` method on an object changes the state of the waiting threads.
The notifying thread only releases the lock once it completes the execution of its synchronized code on the lock object it is going to release.

So here's how it is:

**wait()**
If a thread calls `wait()` method on an object, the thread IMMEDIATELY releases the lock of that object and goes into waiting state.

**notify()**
But when a thread calls `notify()` method on an object, the thread does not release the lock of that object immediately, if the thread have some more job to do (i.e code to execute after notify() call). If the execution of the synchronized code is completed or there are no statements after notify(), then the thread releases the lock for waken up threads from waiting state.

Comment: _"Calling notify() method on an object **releases** the lock of that object."_ and later _"But when a thread calls notify() method on an object, the thread **may not release** the lock of that object immediately"_ in this answer contradict each other.