# when the thread will release the lock on object?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

I am new for multi-threading.currently i am learning lock and notify and synchronize block . i created a small program to check how wait and notify working with synchronize block , if i will not create any thread(i supposed main thread  will get the lock). Below is the code for better understanding .

```
public class Problem1 
{
    public void waitForSignal() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Object obj=new Object();
        synchronized (obj) {
        obj.wait();
        obj.notify();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Problem1 pb=new Problem1();
        pb.waitForSignal();
        System.out.println("hello");//controll not come here
    }

}
```

if i run the above program it will stuck. and control neither goes to notify() and nor it will exit the synchronize block. why code behave like this.
i tried to search on google and i found the below statement

> wait( ) tells the calling thread to give up the monitor and go to
>   sleep until some other thread enters the same monitor and calls
>   notify( ).

what i understand from above statement that , for correct execution of my the program i have to create another thread, that will enter in the same monitor and interrupt the execution of the current lock holding thread. Please make me correct if i am wrong. 
Please me to correct above code , so it will work fine without Stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java ,wait ,notify notifyall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999193/java-wait-notify-notifyall)

Answer (score 3):

When you call `wait`, some other thread will have to acquire the lock on `obj` and call `notify` or `notifyAll` to signal the waiting thread to proceed. The easiest way to understand is in the context of the Consumer/Producer problem, and Oracle has a pretty good tutorial about [that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

Thread interruption is something entirely different. It is a request for the interrupted thread to check its interrupted status and terminate processing. Brian Goetz has a great article about this in the context of [properly handling InterruptedException](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/).

Comment: Thanks for your response , but if you see my program , the control not goes to notify() call , so there is no chance to generate any kind of signal for the waiting thread. Can  you please explain it little bit more. take a reference of my program.

Comment: Control does not go to the `notify` call because the thread is blocked. The only reason you would use `wait` is to coordinate activity with another thread. I would suggest putting your program aside and going through the tutorial.

Comment: What are you waiting for? What notification do you want to signal? I would suggest having a good answer to these questions before proceeding, because taking wait and notify out of context will only lead to confusion.

Comment: @vijayram, in other words, the `obj.wait()` call will not return until some _other_ thread calls `obj.notify()`.  That's what wait() and notify() are for.  You can't do anything useful with wait() and notify() in a program that only has one thread.