# What is the state of Java thread during waiting and unable to obtain lock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Java thread can be held by either:

1. Unable to obtain a lock.
2. Being held by a wait() method.

What is the difference between the above two scenarios in terms of the Java thread state?

Consider the following simple code:

```
   synchronized(object) {
       object.wait();
       System.out.println("Completed.");
   }
```

If two threads (say ThreadA and ThreadB) are all being held at the wait() method. When another thread calls notifyAll(), ThreadA will revive from wait and obtain the lock on object and continue, for example. ThreadB will also revive but unable to get the lock on object and be held until ThreadA exits the synchronized block. ThreadB then obtains the lock and continue.

The result will be two "Completed" are printed.

In this example, there must be a time when ThreadB changes from "Being held by wait()" to "Being held because it is unable to get the lock on object".

I want to know how it works internally in Java. Please help.

Comment: Based on what the Javadoc for `enum Thread.State` (I haven't tried the experiment) the state should change from `WAITING` to `BLOCKED`.  Maybe you could do the experiment and see if I'm right.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28726421/6238076) already explain in very details the behavior of all waiting threads after receiving notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference between being in `object.wait()` state and waiting for the lock on monitor of `object` is that thread in the `object.wait()` state releases all the monitor of `object` held by it, and it will compete with all the threads in the system to reacquire the monitors again. That makes `wait()` a special state.

So in your case when `A` and `B` (Thread A and Thread B) are in wait state, they don't have the monitor for synchronization `object`, both of them have been suspended from execution till some other thread calls `object.notify()` or `object.notifyAll()`. When the `notifyAll()` is called JVM wakes up all the threads (in this case `A` and `B`) in `object.wait()` state and they compete to get the monitor of the current `synchronized` block. If `notify()` is called then JVM picks up a A or B randomly.

It's to be noted here that JVM is not notifying any specific thread, that's why every waiting thread has to wait in a `while(notify_condition_for_me)` loop, that validates if the the wait condition has been if not it has to go in the `object.wait()` state again.

So the correct code should be

```
synchronized(object) {
   while(myResourceArrived) {//like URL data, JDBC data or something
       object.wait();
   }
   System.out.println("Completed.");
}
```

When `A` and `B` are in `object.wait()` state, they have released all the monitors they previously held for `object`, so any other thread which is waiting outside the `synchronized` block will be immediately able to enter the block by acquiring the released monitor of `object`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`Thread.State`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) and more specifically the `WAITING` and `BLOCKED` states.

If you are interested in the internal implementation, both can be achieved using [`LockSupport.park()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#park()) and [`LockSupport.unpark(Thread)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#unpark(java.lang.Thread)), and that's actually how they are implemented in most places.

P.S. In case you are interested, here are the OpenJDK `park()` implementations for [Windows (line 4946)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/hotspot/file/37240c1019fd/src/os/windows/vm/os_windows.cpp) and [Linux (line 5808)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/hotspot/file/37240c1019fd/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp), and here is the [`wait()/notify()/notifyAll()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/hotspot/file/37240c1019fd/src/share/vm/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp) implementation (line 1457). They are very well commented, just give it some time if it all looks too complicated on first glance.